# Window.open not Working inside IE

Tags: javascript

I have window.open as shown below

```
window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name_' + Math.random(),'height=600,width=800');
```

to open a pop up window .

But unfortunately , this code works inside MOzilla , but doesn't work with IE 7 .

Could anybody please advice me on this .

Thank you .

Comment: Does this code sniplet works fro you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use the code given below

```
window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name_' +Math.floor(Math.random()*11),'height=600,width=800');
```